# how to get caret position in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, getcaretpos

I want to get current caret position in my cocoa app from any active application relative to screen position. Please let me know any solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Hey Amit, Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

UIView rectContainingCaretSelection ?

Comment: Thanks, but i am searching solution for cocoa app not for iPhone.